# How can I implement batching in FSharp.Data.GraphQL?

Tags: .net-core, f#, graphql

I am building a GraphQL server using F# with .NET Core. To implement batching and address N+1 select, I am building a data loader. The Facebook's [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) uses Node.js **event loop tick** to collect and dispatch batched requests.

However, such mechanism is not available in .NET Core. I know I can implement `run/dispatch` method from the data loader instance which can be called manually. But, that is something very hard to do from within the **resolvers** which execute independently. So I need some **auto dispatching** mechanism to run the batched requests.

Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Comment: What you ask isn't clear - you're trying to describe what you want by explaining how you'd do it in a completely different technology. Most of Node's mechanisms aren't needed in a fully multithreaded environment like .NET Core.Instead of `what` you posted a different `how`. What are you trying to do? What do you mean by batching? Send multiple requests as a batch? Combine multiple operations as a batch? Perform bulk operations (which is definitely *not* what GraphQL is about)? Or *return* data in pages instead of one long stream?

Comment: Which GraphQL library are you using? This affects what is available or what needs to be built far more than the underlying runtime. Perhaps the library already implements what you want?

Comment: For example [GraphQL .NET includes an implementation of Facebook's DataLoader.](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/guides/dataloader/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using [FSharp.Data.GraphQL](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.GraphQL/) which does not implement DataLoader implementation.

Comment: Most of Node's techniques and mechanisms simply aren't needed in a natively multi-threaded and asynchronous environment like .NET Core. To perform async IO in .NET all you need is to use the async version of an IO operation with `await`. All file and database operations are asynchronous while some classes like HttpClient are async-*only*

Comment: `which does not implement DataLoader` it's .NET though, which means you can even use GraphQL.NET's implementation, or just read the source to see how it works. Again, what are you asking? How to implement DataLoader's exact protocol? Why would you need an event loop then? If you want to load data without blocking, use async operations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The problem with GraphQL.NET is that it doesn't play well with the F# GraphQL library I am using. It also doesn't implement BatchingLoader that I can use across same top level resolvers if I call them using aliases. For example - `query { a: getPerson(123) { id, name } b: getPerson(456) { id, name, age }`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Since, above query would call same resolver twice but **independently**, I have no control over calling the `run/load` method. The dispatch should happen automatically. Even with GraphQL.NET DataLoader, I still have to manually call it which means it is not useful for above type of query. It only applies to nested N+1 problem resolution. The only way it is possible is using some sort of automatic batching albeit optimistically.

Comment: You should put all this in the question *and post your code* because what you actually ask is completely different. So you already tried GraphQL.NET but have some specific requirements that don't work well with its own implementation of DataLoader. What are those, what does your client code look like and how did you try to implement them? Note's event loop has nothing to do with any of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question, which I recently hit myself.

There are a few "data-loader" type libraries for F# and .NET, however if you are also using `FSharp.Data.GraphQL` then there are fewer solutions that integrate well.

Note that the "Haxl" approach will not work (easily) with `FSharp.Data.GraphQL`. This is because the Haxl types must be integrated into GraphQL query models, but `FSharp.Data.GraphQL` only understands sync and `async`.

The most suitable implementation that I could find is in [`FSharp.Core.Extensions`](https://github.com/Horusiath/fsharp.core.extensions). This is fairly new library, but it's high quality and Apache 2.0 licensed.

I'm sure there are many ways it can be integrated it into `FSharp.Data.GraphQL`, however my preferred approach was to put the data-loaders into the root value of the schema. This allows all GraphQL resolvers down the tree to access it.

I think the best way to explain it is to show an example.

Here we have a domain of "People" who can have zero or more "followers", who are also "People". Each person has a globally unique ID. There is significant overlap in the followers between people, so a naive solution may re-fetch the same data repeatedly. Our database layer can fetch many person records in one query, so we would like to leverage that where possible.

You can paste this code into an `.fsx` file and run it. The dependencies are fetched by Paket.

`paket.dependencies`

```
generate_load_scripts: true

source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

storage: none
framework: net5.0, netstandard2.1

nuget FSharp.Core 5.0.0
nuget FSharp.Data.GraphQL.Server 1.0.7

github Horusiath/fsharp.core.extensions:0ff5753bb6f232e0ef3c446ddcc72345b74174ca
```

`DataLoader.fsx`

```ml
#load ".paket/load/net50/FSharp.Data.GraphQL.Server.fsx"

#load "paket-files/Horusiath/fsharp.core.extensions/src/FSharp.Core.Extensions/Prolog.fs"
#load "paket-files/Horusiath/fsharp.core.extensions/src/FSharp.Core.Extensions/AsyncExtensions.fs"

type Person =
  {
    ID : string
    Name : string
  }

// Mocks a real database access layer
module DB =

  // Used to avoid interleaving of printfn calls during async execution
  let private logger = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
    while true do
      let! message = inbox.Receive()

      printfn "DB: %s" message
  })

  let private log x =
    logger.Post(x)

  // Our data-set
  let private people =
    [
      { ID = "alice"; Name = "Alice" }, [ "bob"; "charlie"; "david"; "fred" ]
      { ID = "bob"; Name = "Bob" }, [ "charlie"; "david"; "emily" ]
      { ID = "charlie"; Name = "Charlie" }, [ "david" ]
      { ID = "david"; Name = "David" }, [ "emily"; "fred" ]
      { ID = "emily"; Name = "Emily" }, [ "fred" ]
      { ID = "fred"; Name = "Fred" }, []
    ]
    |> Seq.map (fun (p, fs) -> p.ID, (p, fs))
    |> Map.ofSeq

  let fetchPerson id =
    async {
      log $"fetchPerson {id}"

      match people |> Map.find id with
      | (x, _) -> return x
    }

  let fetchPersonBatch ids =
    async {
      let idsString = String.concat "; " ids
      log $"fetchPersonBatch [ {idsString} ]"

      return
        people
        |> Map.filter (fun k _ -> Set.contains k ids)
        |> Map.toSeq
        |> Seq.map (snd >> fst)
        |> Seq.toList
    }

  let fetchFollowers id =
    async {
      log $"fetchFollowers {id}"

      match people |> Map.tryFind id with
      | Some (_, followerIDs) -> return followerIDs
      | _ -> return []
    }





// GraphQL type definitions

open FSharp.Core
open FSharp.Data.GraphQL
open FSharp.Data.GraphQL.Types

#nowarn "40"

[<NoComparison>]
type Root =
  {
    FetchPerson : string -> Async<Person>
    FetchFollowers : string -> Async<string list>
  }

let rec personType =
  Define.Object(
    "Person",
    fun () -> [
      Define.Field("id", ID, fun ctx p -> p.ID)
      Define.Field("name", String, fun ctx p -> p.Name)
      Define.AsyncField("followers", ListOf personType, fun ctx p -> async {
        let root = ctx.Context.RootValue :?> Root

        let! followerIDs = root.FetchFollowers p.ID

        let! followers =
          followerIDs
          |> List.map root.FetchPerson
          |> Async.Parallel

        return Seq.toList followers
      })
    ])

let queryRoot = Define.Object("Query", [
  Define.AsyncField(
    "person",
    personType,
    "Fetches a person by ID",
    [
      Define.Input("id", ID)
    ],
    fun ctx root -> async {
      let id = ctx.Arg("id")

      return! root.FetchPerson id
    })
])

// Construct the schema once to cache it
let schema = Schema(queryRoot)




// Run an example query...
// Here we fetch the followers of the followers of the followers of `alice`
// This query offers many optimization opportunities to the data-loader

let query = """
  query Example {
    person(id: "alice") {
      id
      name
      followers {
        id
        name
        followers {
          id
          name
          followers {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  """

let executor = Executor(schema)

async {
  // Construct a data-loader for fetch person requests
  let fetchPersonBatchFn (requests : Set<string>) =
    async {
      let! people =
        requests
        |> DB.fetchPersonBatch

      let responses =
        Seq.zip requests people
        |> Map.ofSeq

      return responses
    }

  let fetchPersonContext = DataLoader.context ()
  let fetchPersonLoader = DataLoader.create fetchPersonContext fetchPersonBatchFn

  // Construct a data-loader for fetch follower requests
  let fetchFollowersBatchFn (requests : Set<string>) =
    async {
      let! responses =
        requests
        |> Seq.map (fun id ->
          async {
            let! followerIDs = DB.fetchFollowers id

            return id, followerIDs
          })
        |> Async.Parallel

      return Map.ofSeq responses
    }

  let fetchFollowersContext = DataLoader.context ()
  let fetchFollowersLoader = 
    DataLoader.create fetchFollowersContext fetchFollowersBatchFn

  let root =
    {
      FetchPerson = fun id -> fetchPersonLoader.GetAsync(id)
      FetchFollowers = fun id -> fetchFollowersLoader.GetAsync(id)
    }

  // Uncomment this to see how sub-optimal the query is without the data-loader
  // let root =
  //   {
  //     FetchPerson = DB.fetchPerson
  //     FetchFollowers = DB.fetchFollowers
  //   }

  // See https://bartoszsypytkowski.com/data-loaders/
  do! Async.SwitchToContext fetchPersonContext
  do! Async.SwitchToContext fetchFollowersContext

  // Execute the query
  let! response = executor.AsyncExecute(query, root)

  printfn "%A" response
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```