# Is Suave.io using a single thread for processing requests?

Tags: .net-core, f#, suave

I know `Suave.io` is non-blocking but is it using single thread like Node.js? Is it similar to Kestrel as explained here - [Is Kestrel using a single thread for processing requests like Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40948857/5723098)?

As a context, I am trying to build a data loader for GraphQL using `Suave` and `FSharp.Data.GraphQL`. To perform batching and auto-dispatching, I need to build a clock based batch queue.

Comment: Did you get any success with this? Currently investigating FSharp.Data.GraphQL for my GraphQL backend but no word(documentation or example) on a dataLoader support is really pushing me away from it

Comment: @MRainzo Nope, I did not. Coming from Node.js background, I though I could build a similar Data Loader but Async in .NET is way different. In fact, `async` resolution with threading is not predictable. Either, you need instrumentation like what [HotChocolate](https://chillicream.com/platform) has done or rely on timer based batching. I have added the sample implementation here [Gitter F# GraphQL channel](https://gitter.im/FSharp-Data-GraphQL/community).

Comment: @MRainzo Alternately, you can consider using HotChocolate. It is not as good and as functional as `FSharp.Data.GraphQL` but it gets the job done. Mostly you end up writing classes and objects. F# is awesome languages but ecosystem is very problematic. I have switched to Elixir for back-end development. It provides everything that a modern Web Application would need.

Comment: I am  also considering switching from F# but I really love the language. I will investigate Elixir as I've heard some good things about it

Comment: There is a question about data-loaders in FSharp.Data.GraphQL here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685864/how-can-i-implement-batching-in-fsharp-data-graphql?rq=1

Comment: You can use Giraffe (and other ASP.NET based libraries) with FSharp.Data.GraphQL. These are multi-threaded.